# google calendar api: when do calendar usage limits reset

Tags: google-calendar-api

I've been doing some bulk uploads and my code rate limits the API calls to below the API limit. However, during testing I've created a lot of events and have hit this limit. Is it possible to have the limit lifted? How long before the limit resets?

I've tried waiting for some time but now no inserts are accepted

I'm using `calendar.events.insert()`

returns

`403 Forbidden Calendar usage limits exceeded.`

Answer (score 1):

You can see the API usage limits [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/pricing) and [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en).

As of today (11 Oct 2019), they are as follows:

- 1,000,000 total queries per day
- 100,000 created events in a short period of time
- 60 calendars created in a short period of time
- 10,000 invites to external guests in a short period of time
- 2,000 emails sent through 'Email guests' feature in a short period of time
- 750 calendar shares in a short period of time

I'm afraid the best option to have is to wait for tomorrow/for a while, as quota increase requests may take a while. You can also see the usage you have given it in the quotas section of the API Console, so you can better understand how it works and to prevent this happening again.

Comment: I'm well below the API usage limits. `Calendar usage limits exceeded` refers to the number of events _created_ in a calendar not API's calls. When a large number are created in a short space of time this is the error.

Comment: @PaulBlacknell You are absolutely right, sorry for misunderstanding your question, I apologise. I have updated the answer with this information.

Comment: The Google calendar usage limit says...

`If you create more than 100,000 events in calendar during a short period, you might lose calendar edit ability for a few hours.
It may take several months until this limit type is fully replenished.`

I haven't created anything like this many (maybe a few hundred) and so I don't understand how it replenishes.

Anyone from Google watching?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create event even its just one ?

I am experiencing the same issue even my limit is far below the API usage limit

In my case, i only create one event using `calendar.events.insert`

Few days ago, i found [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141704931) in google issue tracker

Comment: Occasionally I can. but after a few they then fail. I'm trying to insert lots and after a few (typically 3-4) it starts rejecting. Then consistently fails before, after a few hours of waiting, I get a couple of successes. I reviewed the issue and my events have attendees but they're all google calendar users.